# How to resolve ambiguity inside a lambda that inside a static method?

Tags: c++, lambda, static

I'm trying to write logging feature that will print object id if it is exist.
VS 2019 compiles and works fine but Clang fails. How to get worked for Clang?

NOTE: "log" member can be present or absent - depends from class developer. It is optional. Global "log" variable will be present always.

Short example:

```
int i = 0;

struct S {
    int i = 1;

    int f() {
        return i;
    }

    static int g() {
        return [&](){
            return i;
        }();
    }
};
```

full example

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cassert>
#include <string>

using std::string;

#define LOG(x) [&]() \
    { \
      log.print(x); \
    } \
    ();

namespace myspace {

class Log
{
public:
  Log(string id)
    : m_Id(id)
  {
  }
  void print(const string& str)
  {
    printf("%s %s\n",m_Id.c_str(),str.c_str());
  }
private:
  string m_Id;
};

Log log("global_id");

class MyClass
{
public:
  MyClass()
    : log("local_id")
  {
  }
  void doSomething()
  {
    LOG("doSomething");
  }
  static void doSomethingStatic()
  {
    LOG("doSomethingStatic");
  }
public:
  Log log;

};

void test()
{
  MyClass obj;
  obj.doSomething();
  MyClass::doSomethingStatic();
}
  
}// ns

int main()
{
  myspace::test();
  return 0;
}
```

Expected output (VS 2019, compilation success):

```
local_id doSomething
global_id doSomethingStatic
```

Actual output(clang version 8.0.1, compilation error)

```
main.cpp(46,5): error: invalid use of member 'log' in static member function
main.cpp(10,7): note: expanded from macro 'LOG'
```

Comment: This is clever, but possibly too clever.

Comment: From the experience, it is more likely that MSVC is wrong to accept this code, rather than gcc and clang to refuse to compile it. It would need some language-lawyer to backup with standard quote tho.

Comment: [Here's a shorter example](https://godbolt.org/z/LvxZ0A). Seems like when using `[&]`, msvc captures `::log` instead of `MyClass::log`, so it compiles, but gcc and clang capture the member (which fails because it's a static function)

Answer (score 5):

You are doing unqualified name lookup. The standard says this (emphasis mine):

> [[basic.lookup.unqual]#1](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.lookup#unqual-1)
>   In all the cases listed in [basic.lookup.unqual], the scopes are searched for a declaration in the order listed in each of the respective categories; **name lookup ends as soon as a declaration is found for the name.**
>   If no declaration is found, the program is ill-formed.

The note [[class.static.mfct]#1](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.static#mfct-1) clarifies that the rules of [[class.mfct]](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.mfct) also apply to static member functions. Those include [another note](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.mfct#4.sentence-2) that refers us to [basic.unqual.lookup].

Regarding this being in a lambda, we can find:

> [[expr.prim.lambda.closure]#12](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.prim.lambda#closure-12)
>   The *lambda-expression*'s *compound-statement* yields the *function-body* ([dcl.fct.def]) of the function call operator, but for purposes of name lookup [...], the *compound-statement* is considered in the context of the *lambda-expression*.

In other words, name lookup in the lambda function body happens as if we were in the surrounding scope (the static member function), so the above still applies.

You [cannot](https://godbolt.org/z/URovCV) circumvent this with explicit captures either (i.e. `[&log](){...}();`), because

> [[expr.prim.lambda.capture]](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.prim.lambda#capture-4)
>   The *identifier* in a *simple-capture* is looked up using the usual rules for unqualified name lookup; [...]

In the end, it boils down to the above bold highlight: **Unqualified name lookup stops as soon as a matching name is found** (whether you wanted that name or not). Since the non-static `log` member is found before the global `log` variable, lookup stops there. I don't think you can work around this problem, it's just how unqualified lookup and (static) member functions are specified to work. Qualified name lookup is (for once) not the way out, for obvious reasons.

Comment: Big thanks for the answer! Is it good to push VS behavior to the language standard?

Comment: @Smak I like the original idea, but I fear that [[class.static.mfct\]](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.static.mfct) gives us nothing to work with to ever distinguish whether we are in a static or non-static member function... And yes, it would be good if the different compilers all followed the C++ standard closely. It would make portability less of a headache.

Answer (score 0):

If you make `Log` into a functor then your macro and lambda achieve very little and can be removed resolving the ambiguity is then fairly simple:

```
namespace myspace {

class Log
{
public:
  Log(string id)
    : m_Id(id)
  {
  }
  void operator()(const string& str)
  {
    printf("%s %s\n",m_Id.c_str(),str.c_str());
  }
private:
  string m_Id;
};

Log log("global_id");

class MyClass
{
public:
  MyClass()
    : log("local_id")
  {
  }
  void doSomething()
  {
    log("doSomething");
  }
  static void doSomethingStatic()
  {
    myspace::log("doSomethingStatic");
  }
public:
  Log log;

};
```

If you don't like having to do `myspace::log` then you can change the name of the global to something like `glog` or `slog`.

Comment: Thanks for answer, but it is required same typing when calling log function.